# Django reverse relations

Tags: python, django

I've managed to get my around Django for the most part but I'm still doing a pattern which I'm sure there exists a better way of doing but reading related questions I can't find a solution that works for me. It's a simple reverse relationship lookup which is then looped through in the template:

```
items_a = ItemA.objects.filter(foo='bar')
for item in items_a:
    items_a.items_b = ItemB.objects.filter(item_a=item_a)
```

I then use this so loop though in the template

Item A 1

- Item B 1
- Item B 2

Item A 2

- Item B 3
- Item B 4

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to populate the `items_b` property in a loop. Use the [backward relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) instead:

```
items_a = ItemA.objects.filter(foo='bar')
```

And the in the template:

```
{% for item in items_a %}
    <h2>{{ item }}</h2>
    <ul>
    {% for item_b in item.itemb_set.all %}
        <li>{{ item_b }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```